# Why can't I edit comments past 5 minutes?

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-edits

It's quite annoying to find that you can't edit comments past five minutes, I completely understand not editing comments after 5 minutes that have a reply after them (although it's a bit weird you can delete them), but if the comment is still the last in the "thread". You can copy the comment, delete it and repost it edited. That overrides what you have on the clipboard, is annoying and gives more a chance for you comment to become out of place if someone posts, while you are copying, editing and pasting.

Comment: testing comments

Comment: hellow testing comments